# JPA unidirectional one to one

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 JPAs. UserJPA and PostJPA.
UserJPA has all the user details, like name, address, id. 
Post JPA has a user_id column. It's a foreign key to User table's id column

when i save the post, i don't want to update the user table, but when i fetch the post table, i want to get the user information

````
@Table(name = "post_tbl")
public class PostJPA {

@Column(name = "user_id")
private Integer userId;

@Column(name = "content")
@NotNull
private String content;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
UserJPA user = new UserJPA();
}


@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(name = "user_tbl")
public class UserJPA {
@Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotNull
    private String email;
} ```

Why is a save done on PostJPA trying to insert an entry on the User?
````

Comment: Have you set any cascade in your "user_id" foreign key in the "post_tbl" table?

Comment: Nope. Didnt add Cascade

Answer (score 1):

Because you are assigning a new, not persisted user to it with

`UserJPA user = new UserJPA();`

You should assign existing user to the post before saving it

Comment: @user2200551 if this answer worked, consider accepting it

Comment: Hi @user2200551 if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.